# IndexError al intentar filtrar array de tres dimensiones mediante lista por compresión

Tags: python, numpy, indices

Tengo el siguiente ejercicio:

> Agrega una condición a la lista por compresión anterior de tal forma que el último valor de cada sub-array se imprima, pero solo si es menor o igual que 0.5.

y estoy utilizando el siguiente código:

```
b = np.array([[[0.55867166, 0.06210792, 0.08147297],
        [0.82579068, 0.91512478, 0.06833034]],

       [[0.05440634, 0.65857693, 0.30296619],
        [0.06769833, 0.96031863, 0.51293743]],

       [[0.09143215, 0.71893382, 0.45850679],
        [0.58256464, 0.59005654, 0.56266457]],

       [[0.71600294, 0.87392666, 0.11434044],
        [0.8694668 , 0.65669313, 0.10708681]],

       [[0.07529684, 0.46470767, 0.47984544],
        [0.65368638, 0.14901286, 0.23760688]]])

listn5x2x3=[item for sublist in (b) for item in sublist for item in sublist if item[3] <=0.5]
print(listn5x2x3)
```

pero no me da este error:

> IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3

Answer (score 1):

En Python (y por extensión en NumPy) los índices son base 0, es decir, el primer item tiene índice 0 no 1, por lo que el último índice de un array de tres items es 2 no 3.

Aparte de ésto, no estás filtrando correctamente, en vez de agregar el item agregas el array de la tercera dimensión al completo, debería ser:

```
listn5x2x3 = [
    subsublist[2] for sublist in b for subsublist in sublist
        if subsublist[2] <= 0.5
        ]
```

o usando indizado negativo:

```
listn5x2x3 = [
    subsublist[-1] for sublist in b for subsublist in sublist
        if subsublist[-1] <= 0.5
        ]
```

El índice `-1` se corresponde con el último item, `-2` con el penúltimo, etc

En Python >= 3.8 te puedes ahorrar un indizado usando expresiones de asignación (operador "walrus" `:=`):

**`Python >= 3.8`**

```
listn5x2x3 = [
    item for sublist in b for subsublist in sublist
        if (item:= subsublist[-1]) <= 0.5
        ]
```

La salida en todos los casos es:

```
[0.08147297, 0.06833034, 0.30296619, 0.45850679,
 0.11434044, 0.10708681, 0.47984544, 0.23760688]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!